# database error when import sql file

Tags: mysql

Errormessage while trying to connect to MySQL:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'your username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tinyCMS-master\index.php on line 4
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'your username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Hi, you should be a little bit more specific on your question. This problem looks like the very usual problem: you supplied incorrect login credentials. Google is in that sense very helpful. If you feel like there is something else going on, don't forget to add to your question!

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the user name or password is incorrect.